# Invalid argument: Incompatible shapes: [20,2209] vs. [20,4418] in conv1D in feature set

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to build a separable CNN 1D model with strides values as "2". But it throws incompatible shape error in feature set. My input is a text file. In a file i have 20 different file separated by newline. Each file has 4418 lines.

My Keras version is 2.2.5. TF is 1.12.

I have changed metric based on GitHub but nothing changed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Shanmugavalli G You can try with paddig= "same" and try to run the model. If you are still getting the same error, please mention it here.